# HTML - Incorrect media type still correctly displays a base64 image

Tags: html, media-type

My webpage displays an image from a base64 string.

Even if I put a wrong media type, the image is still rendered correctly (I use Firefox). For example:

```
src="data:incorrect;base64, ...base 64 string..."
```

Is there any reason for that ?

Moreover, I cannot know in advance the format of the image to display (as they are uploaded by the user), so, should I use simply `image` as a media-type ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Browsers may display some common image types such as jpeg, png etc without proper mime type. but images in the form of SVG and all will not identify by the browser with out proper mime type. so it is better to use proper mime type even if it is working for you without proper mime.

Comment: Got it thanks. And do you know about my second question ? I cannot know in advance what will be the image format (it may be png or jpeg). Should I simply use the `image` mime-type ?

Comment: @jean553 images are uploaded to the server in the form of Multipart. file type is also stored the Multipart image file. based on the server side technology you are using you can separate the file extension.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

the format is :

```
 data:{mimeType};base64,{code}
```

the mimeType maybe is:

```
data:text/html
data:text/javascript,Javascript
data:image/png;base64 
data:image/jpeg;base64
```

only {code} is used for image.

in fact, if you use

```
<img src=a.jpg>
```

can diaplay, even if you change ext as a.asp

```
<img src=a.asp>
```

the image still can show.

some virus can use this method, but I think when base64 string, the ";"'s data is not used ,you can just split ";" it and only get the {code}